# same area for all violins independent of facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, facet

I want to create a plot for three different factors where all violins have the same area. But using `facet_grid(. ~ C)` seems to force the violins within each facet (i.e. just those within a level of factor C) to have the same area. How can I overcome this?

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(value = c(906, 1013, 1109, 876, 747, 759, 876, 1358, 739, 
                          1086, 807, 954, 1586, 762, 1353, 1221, 976, 1002, 
                          1129, 943, 1270, 1126, 853, 950, 677, 696, 681, 
                          615, 736, 595, 590, 618, 524, 1014, 515, 645, 860, 
                          874, 934, 728, 1078, 659, 1024, 786, 821, 541,
                          681, 744),
                A = gl(2, 12, 48),
                B = gl(2, 6, 48),
                C = gl(2, 24))

ggplot(d, aes(x = A, y = value, fill = B)) +
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE, scale = "area") +
  facet_grid(. ~ C)
```

[image]

Comment: Simplest solution would be to use a `x = C:A` with additional formating is `scales_x_discrete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we will create a new `data.frame` with precalculated densities:

```
library('tidyverse')

d2 <- d %>%
  group_by(A, B, C) %>%
  do({
    dens <- density(.$value)
    tibble(x = c(head(dens$x, 1), dens$x, tail(dens$x, 1)), #Add 0s at end to close lines
           y = c(0, dens$y, 0))
  }) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(ymin = as.numeric(A:B) - .4*y/max(y), # Add offset for factor levels
         ymax = as.numeric(A:B) + .4*y/max(y))
```

And now we will plot the densities as ribbons:

```
ggplot(d2)+
  aes(x = x,
      ymin = ymin,
      ymax = ymax,
      group = A:B,
      fill = B)+
  geom_ribbon()+

  # Enclosing lines
  geom_line(aes(y = ymin))+
  geom_line(aes(y = ymax))+

  facet_grid(. ~ C)+

  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1.5, 2.5),
                     minor_breaks = c(1.5, 3.5),
                     labels = levels(d2$A))+

  labs(x = 'value', y = 'A')+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this smart solution. Can you explain why the violins within the facet on the left (for C == 2) stay the same and only the violins on the right (for C == 1) change their areas compared to my original plots?

Comment: And is it possible to do something like `trim = FALSE` (i. e. trim the tails of the violins to the range of the data) with your method?

Comment: @statmerkur, basically because of this `.4*y/max(y)`. In ggplot `max` is selected in each facet (also it should be `.5` for exact match). In our case we use  general `max` for scaling which occurs in second facet, so only first one appears differently. For `trim = TRUE` you should calculate density as `density(.$value, from = min(.$value), to = max(.$value))` inside `do()`.

Comment: your suggestions does the trick and covers all aspects of my question. But is there no way to manipulate the scaling within the facets if one uses `geom_violin()` and `facet_grid()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Both of the below give the same plot as the faceted one:

ggplot(d, aes(x = paste(C,A), y = value, fill = B)) +
geom_violin(trim = FALSE, scale = "area") 

ggplot(d, aes(x =  C:A, y = value, fill = B)) +
geom_violin(trim = FALSE, scale = "area")
```

It will be good if you can describe the purpose of your plot. As other approaches might serve your purpose better like back to back densities or ggridges::geom_density_ridges2:

```
ggplot(d,
aes(x = value, y = paste(A,B), fill = B, height = ..density..))+
ggridges::geom_density_ridges2(scale = 1.2,alpha=0.2,stat = "density")+
facet_grid(. ~ C)+
ggridges::theme_ridges()+
coord_flip()
```

Comment: Is there no way to use facets and get violins that have the same area at the same time? (I have to use violin plots)

Comment: as per the example above and the documentation of geom_violin scale argument:
_if "area" (default), all violins have the same area (before trimming the tails). If "count", areas are scaled proportionally to the number of observations. If "width", all violins have the same maximum width._ 
I see no difference in your plot when we facet or do not facet. I suggest that you edit your title as it is not related to faceting.

Comment: There is a difference if one uses `geom_violin(trim = FALSE, scale = "area")` and `facet_grid(. ~ C)` as I do. Only the violins within each facet/factor level have the same area but I want all the violins to have the same area.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification as far as I know and as per the docs scaling is done before trimming ! you might consider hacking geom_density to do what you want.
    ggplot(d, aes(x=value,  fill=B))  +
 geom_density(aes(y=-..scaled..),trim=TRUE,alpha=0.5)+
 geom_density(aes(y=+..scaled..),trim=TRUE,alpha=0.5)+
  facet_grid(. ~C+A+B)+
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),,
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())+
        coord_flip()

Comment: This method splits the plot into 8 facets. I would like to do a plot like the one shown in my post (i.e. 2 facets) but with the same are for all violins.